# Difference and best way to do Collection´s Assignment, Shallow Copy, Lazy Copy and Deep copy

Tags: java, pointers, collections, reference, copy

EDIT: updated info with answers

I am trying to have an overall view of collection different ways of copying. I think I am getting the concept but need so rounding, and I need is also useful to have such a piece of summary (feel free to modify my post). I have:

Collection a,b; //I omit generics

So what are my chances of copying the collection?:

- Assignment (exactly same object)

  ```
  a=b
  ```
- Shallow copy (2 diff collections, same object references, so if we add/delete one object from one list, is not reflected in the other)

  ```
  a = new ArrayList(b);  // Or any other implementation of Collections

  a = b.clone(); //This also? 

  b = new ArrayList(); //This also?
  for (Object o : a) b.add(a);
  ```
- Lazy Copy (Same as shallow in java?)
- Deep Copy (different lists with copied Objects, so modifying one list or object does not affect the other)

  ```
  b = new ArrayList(); // Or any other implementation of Collections
  for (Object o : a) b.add(o.clone());
  ```

So I imagine these cases:

## Collection Copying/duplication (or returning DAO data)

```
                       SyncStateOfListing    OriginalListingSafe   OriginalObjectsStateSafe  
 Mutual aware of changs
 **********************
 Assignment in other var         y - Mirrored         n                      n
 Iterator*                       y - Concurrnt.Exc    n (remove())           n    

 New is aware of old´ changes (RO ProxyView)
 ******************************************

 Coll.unmodifiableColl(orig)     y - Mirrored**       y NotSuppOpExc on RW   n  
 Coll.unmodif(orig).iterator()*  y - Concurrnt.Exc    y NotSuppOpExc on RW   n
 Enum                            y - ?                y No RW methods                  

 Independent copies
 ******************
 Shallow Copy                    n                    y                      n
 Deep Copy                       n                    y                      y (expensive) 


 * Iterator we force to regenerate it in any use and we get Exceptions if at some moment the snapshot is obsolete, so we assure the state for which the operation is meant, transactionally. Cannot add elements or retraverse.
 ** The "new" collection is totally mirrored for any change on the original, but internally, inner iterator is always used when traversing (the obvious stateful operation) so we get the same properties as when using it
```

Are all right my assumptions?

Answer (score 2):

Assignment : 
a and b will point to the same list, so there won't be any copy there.

Shallow and Lazy seem equivalent to me. 
The references to the objects in the list will be the same. You may say it like this : "same objects will be present in the two lists". So modifying an object of one list also modifies it in the second since this is the same object.

Lastly I think you should write this for deep copy :

```
b = new ArrayList();
for (Object o : a) b.add(o.clone()); // and not a.clone()
```

This way you can modify one object in list a without modifying the copy in list b.

Warning: using cloneable objects has some limitations. See JDK docs for details.